# Getting a numeric value out of a string

Tags: sql-server-2008

In a table named `TRY` I have a column `ABC` which has records with value `abc:30|def:g h i|j:k|l:m|n:o|p: |q: 0.25 |r:0.47|s:t u`

I want to fetch the numeric value after `r:` The example given has value as **r:0.47** But it can also have a value as **123456.012596363**

I am not sure on using patindex. Can anyone please help.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...........

```
declare @abc nvarchar(100) =  'abc:30|def:g h i|j:k|l:m|n:o|p: |q: 0.25 |r:0.47|s:t u'  

select 
substring(substring(@abc,charindex('r:',@abc) + 2 ,len(@abc)),
            1,
            charindex('|',substring(@abc,charindex('r:',@abc) + 2,len(@abc))) - 1)
```

use this query for your table

```
  select 
    substring(substring(abc,charindex('r:',abc) + 2 ,len(abc)),
                1,
                charindex('|',substring(abc,charindex('r:',abc) + 2,len(abc))) - 1)


    from  TRY
```

-----Final Try

```
  select case when charindex('r:',abc) = 0 then abc else 
    substring(substring(abc,charindex('r:',abc) + 2 ,len(abc)),
                1,
                charindex('|',substring(abc,charindex('r:',abc) + 2,len(abc))) - 1) end


    from  TRY
```

Comment: Hi Kishore, thanks for taking the time for answering this. I am getting this error - Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Please help if possible. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Proud2bOZ Please Try the final query which i have posted above.

Comment: Hi Kishore, Many Thanks For helping on this. I really appreciate the time and effort you have put in. Cheers Mate